# iOS CoreLocation not working over 3G in USA only

Tags: iphone, gps, core-location, 3g

My app is unable to determine lat/long coordinates over 3G in North America. It works perfectly when connected to Wi-Fi. This has been confirmed with both AT&T and Verizon with iOS 5. In the UK it works as expected on both 3G and Wi-Fi with o2.

I'm really stumped as to what the cause may be. I think my code is quite forgiving with regards to accuracy, but as I'm on the other side of the pond, I could be way off?

Can anyone sport any glaring mistakes in my code? (I've removed some unrelated methods).

```
static NSTimeInterval MaxLocationAge = 60.0; // Seconds.
static CLLocationAccuracy DesiredHorizontalAccuracy = 200.0; // Meters.
static NSTimeInterval UpdateTimeout = 30.0; // Seconds.

@implementation AFLocation

@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager, delegate = _delegate, bestEffortAtLocation = _bestEffortAtLocation, updateStartedAt = _updateStartedAt;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager = manager;
        [manager release];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;    
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update
{
    self.updateStartedAt = [NSDate date];
    isUpdating = YES;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.updateStartedAt] > UpdateTimeout) {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        if (isUpdating) {
            [self updateDidTimeout];            
        }
        isUpdating = NO;
    }

    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (locationAge > MaxLocationAge) {
     return;   
    }

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (self.bestEffortAtLocation == nil || self.bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;

        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= DesiredHorizontalAccuracy) {
            self.bestEffortAtLocation = nil;
            isUpdating = NO;
            [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

            [self didUpdateWithDesiredAccuracyToLocation:newLocation];            
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I just had someone in the US try out an app called GPS Status from the App Store. The initial horizontal accuracy was over 800 meters, yet the actual coordinates were pretty accurate. Is this normal in the US? What value do most people limit their horizontal accuracy to?

Comment: I'm located in US, tried out the GPS Status and get accuracy 72m on both WI-FI and 3G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi and 3G are only used to speed up the process of getting a high accuracy (<300m) location.  Without internet connectivity it can take 3-10 *minutes* to get a fix using GPS only.  (They are used for low accuracy fixes with cell tower or wifi triangulation and also to download the satellite ephemeris data to speed up GPS signal acquisition).

The initial fix with WiFi or 3G could be around 800m accuracy that's expected, but if the device has 3G (or WiFi or Edge) connectivity and can get a strong enough signals from the GPS satellites it should be able to get a GPS position within 20-90 seconds.

Perhaps you're app isn't waiting long enough, or the user has weak GPS signal, or has a device without GPS (ie: iPhone1 or iPod Touch or non-3G iPads).  In that case they won't get enough the 200m accuracy required.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `CLLocationManager` to use a desired accuracy of `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`, but you're comparing the location's accuracy with an arbitrary accuracy of 200 meters. With `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` being an opaque type, how do you know that the manager is even striving for your 200 meter accuracy? When I receive location updates, I check to see if the accuracy is less than or equal to the desired accuracy set on my location manager.

Comment: From reading around other resources, it appears kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation is the best option for higher accuracy. Why wouldn't it be striving for best accuracy with this setting? What have you set the desired accuracy to in your app?

Comment: My point is that you don't know exactly what the accuracy of that option is in meters, so comparing it to a random metric may not ever provide a situation where a new location meets that criteria.